# Python & Tweepy Not Playing Well Together

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda, tweepy

I currently have Python 3.6 and am needing to download Tweepy and Install it to Python. I'm currently using Spyder as well. I'm fairly new to this whole thing but I have researched this online the last 5 hours with no luck. Even until Anaconda decided to no longer work and had to be uninstalled and reinstalled. Can someone please help me? I am working with an iMac as well.

How do I install Tweepy in Anaconda?

Comment: You never actually said what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is that I can't get Tweepy to install into Python, no matter what I've tried. I read that PiP came with Python 3.6 but when i give the command to PIP install Tweepy it comes back invalid syntax

Comment: If it's invalid syntax, that means you have it. You just need to lookup a guide on how to use pip.

Comment: For instance when I enter pip install tweepy, this is what pythons response is  runfile('/Users/DeniseBaldwin/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/DeniseBaldwin')
  File "/Users/DeniseBaldwin/untitled1.py", line 1
    pip install tweepy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I know that this is something that I am doing incorrectly but I can't figure it out on my own. Do you mind to troubleshoot with me?

Comment: Wait, are you running that in a .py file? Isn't pip run from the command line?

Comment: see!!! i know I'm not doing something right! please help me

Comment: This is the kind of thing a pip tutorial will cover. I haven't written Python or used pip in a little over 2 years.